# Finite Hindman theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, harmonic-analysis, additive-combinatorics

Consider the following finite version Hindman theorem:
For every sufficiently large $N\in\omega$ and 2-partition of $N=N_0\cup N_1$, there are $i<2,a,b,c\in N_i$ such that $a+b=c$.

The only proof I know for this is by iteratively using Hales-Jewett theorem. What are the alternative proofs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is Schur's theorem, it follows from Ramsey theorem: consider the complete graph with vertices $1,\ldots,N+1$ and color the edge between vertices $i$ and $j$ with color $s\in \{0,1\}$ iff $|i-j|\in N_i$. A monochromatic triangles provides a monochromatic solution of $a+b=c$.

Comment: See https://www.sfu.ca/~vjungic/RamseyNotes/sec_SchurThm.html for a *nicely* illustrated proof.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I think another answer to the question as posed is "check two-colourings of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ by hand''. Certainly this gives a more effective bound than iterative applications of the HJ theorem.